# How do i publish videos with jw player 6 on facebook?

Tags: jwplayer

`https://www.themeflock.com/jw-player/player.swf?config=http://www.themeflock.com/config/config.xml`

This code should work fine as i think but it doesn't any suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can embed jwplayer 6 on facebook:
http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1826071-embedding-jw-player-onto-facebook

The potential issues that get in the way are the need for the premium version of their player, no HLS support, no custom skinning, no advertising, no API access, no analytics, and no HTML5 Playback.

As to your code, it would look something like this: https://www.themeflock.com/jw-player/player.swf?file=http%3A//www.themeflock.com/config/name-of-file.mp4&autostart=true

There are of course other variables you can pass. JWPlayer's documentation goes over this in detail, so I recommend that you consult their docs.

P.S. Make sure to setup your OG Tags properly so the player will load/play/look correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to embed jwplayer 6 on facebook.

You can embed only version 5 of jwplayer.
Follow this guide:

http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player/